# How to replace NVRAM battery in BlueArc storage?

Tags: linux, raid, storage, battery

The RAID/NVRAM battery on a BlueArc Mercury storage host is located in the front of the storage head, and can be replaced without down time. From what I can gather, after battery change, I have to enter its Linux mode, and enter "something".

Does anyone know what "this something" is?

**Update**

How to change a battery is not documented in the manuals, as it is normally a task that you pay a certified BlueArc engineer for. So how to do it is not documented in anything that is available to the owner.

Comment: Have you tried something aqs abstruse as "reading the documentation"? Seriously - what is next? How do I plug a computer into the power grid?

Comment: It looks like you've lost our goodwill, it's time to start doing what you should have done for some time and learn to find things out for yourself. You should also read [this](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question) and the linked documents therin.

Comment: I understand your concerns, but it not explained in the documentation.  Please see my updated post.

Comment: To be quite fair, the answer to this does _not_ reveal itself very quickly from a simple Google search.

Comment: To be quite fair, sometimes a person has to know the proper path for getting certain problems resolved and questions answered, which is to firstly contact the vendor, not a question and answer web site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call BlueArc (now Hitachi Data Systems) and book one of their engineers to come and fix your array.

You do have a support contract right? Right?

These things have support because of issues like this.

---

Incidentally, more for future reference, google keywords, etc.  I found the answer after much searching.

The commands you have to run are:

1. `battery-fitted --field --confirm`
2. `/etc/init.d/chassis-monitor restart`

Source: http://www.hds.com/assets/pdf/hus-file-module-hardware-reference.pdf Page 45-47

Exact Google Search was: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hitachi+nas+cli+reference&oq=hitachi+nas+cli+reference&ie=UTF-8#q=hitachi+nas+cli+nvram+battery

Comment: I moved all critical data from the host before the support ran out. It was a nice box, but way too expensive for our needs. The Mercury model  have EOL this year, so the support is even higher now. I would like to  change the battery myself, because it is "so easy" (just write the correct CLI command) after battery change.

Comment: @Sandra You're probably better off getting rid of it. My own personal opinion is that requiring a paid support call for something that ridiculously simple is an indication that you really don't want the product.

Comment: About 2-3 years ago, I did the Hitachi NAS Administration certification.  Replacing the NVRAM battery was not included in this course.  Probably because it's not a user serviceable part.

Comment: @Sandra Finally found the real answer for you.  Probably.  Maybe.

Comment: That was significantly difficult to find.  I suspect it probably wasn't meant to be found.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, it is officially phased out from production, but it just a shame to throw it out I think, as it have always "just worked". So I will use it for temp space, where the data can be regenerated if it breaks, so no harm done.

Comment: If you read that hardware guide in the link I edited into my answer, there's info on replacing the NVRAM battery.

Comment: @TomO'Connor Can I ask how you found this document, as it is exactly what I was looking for, and the word BlueArc is not even mentioned anywhere.

Comment: You have to know the following things.  1) Bluearc Mercury are more or less = Hitachi NAS Platform. 2) You want the hardware reference guide. - The one they give to service engineers. 3) Google. Lots. .  Took me about 20 minutes.

Comment: Mostly intuition, HNAS experience and being far better at googling than you are.

Comment: @TomO'Connor Those are very good tips. I haven't thought about doing a search from a service engineers point of view. Very clever! Thanks a lot for the doc and search tips!